# T SQL Delete Insert instead of Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

I have a new table that I am getting updates from a web service.  I get 20 Offers for each product and want to update the entire block of data for that product (It seems to me that just deleting & Inserting would be cheaper than processing the 20 offers and identifying which records need deleted, which need updated and which need inserted.

I am have some experience with SQL, but this sort of thing is a bit above my head.  What would be the best way to implement this sort of solution.  I realize that the general consensus says that Update is better than Delete/Insert, but I think that in this case, Delete/Insert is the way to go.

Currently I am creating a DataTable in my C#, and passing it into a stored proc. From there I am deleting any "old" data for the products in my data table (Up to 10 products...with a max of 20 offers each)  I think insert the new data and move happily along my way.   This works, but I would like to increase my speed.

I realize this is a somewhat broad question, but I appreciate any and all suggestions.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

This is a performance issue due to the number of times I will be having to call this stored procedure per day (up to a million)

Comment: You should consider the `MERGE` statement.

Comment: It's 200 rows? Just do whatever works and worry about optimising performance when you're doing 200,000 rows. If you're actually having performance issues right now we'll need to see your actual code and some query plans from the stored procedure to work out what's going on.

Comment: Seems small per transaction, but per day, this sproc will be aprox 1 million times a day, thus it becomes more of a performance issue.

Comment: IMHO, your choice of using User Define Type is correct.DML on 200 rows at one go is no big deal.At the same time this proc will be hit million times a day,that means proc will be hit per second or may be twice per second,this is way too much.It is hard to comment further without viewing table design,index  etc.